# Cleaner syntax for calling a function on condition

Tags: c#, function, syntax, parameters, conditional-statements

I find myself doing the following kind of snippets a lot

```
if(bar != null)
   foo(bar)     // That is, pass in object 'bar' to function 'foo' if bar is not null
```

EDIT: The foo function is from an API and I don't have access to it's code. Essentially the API's function expects a non-null input.

Is there a cleaner C# way to do this? Or am I doing something architecturally incorrect if I find myself doing this a lot?

Apologies if this is a repeat, I can't seem to find the right words for the search.

I have tried to use the new coalescing operator to achieve this, but that can't be used to call a function. Not sure if ternary operators can be used to achieve this either.

I expect there to be a one line way of doing this. Kind of like

```
bar ?? foo(bar) // That is run foo with bar when bar is not null.
```

Comment: What's "unclean" about an "if/else" statement?!?

Comment: There's a cleaner way, try using aggregating functions like `TrueForAll(array, predicate)` with collections, or try LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You may null check inside the foo method:

```
void foo(object bar)
{
    if(bar == null) return;
    //your lines of code
}
```

then you can just run as:

```
foo(bar);
```

Comment: I guess I should have made that clear. The foo function is from an API that I don't have access to. Essentially the API's function expects a non-null input. Editing my post ... Thanks!

Comment: the you just have to go with your if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for instance that would look something like this:

```
bar != null ? foo(bar) : * ;
```

where at `*` you would insert the statement you would like to execute if `bar == null`.

Comment: I guess if I didn't have anything to execute when bar == null, i could just do

```
bar != null ? foo(bar) : return;
```

That's one way of doing it I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @KishoreVenkateshan  You can leave it open like this `bar != null ? foo(bar) : ;` or if you instantly want to return use the return keyword like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> am I doing something architecturally incorrect if I find myself doing this a lot?

Perhaps.  You should generally know whether your variables can ever be null, and omit the checks.  C# 8 is introducing a feature to help you declare, verify and enforce that a reference can not be null: [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Comment: Ah this is actually better! Thanks for pointing me to this. I will make sure to read further about the new C# 8 features.